# PHP MySQLI Prevent SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, security, mysqli, code-injection

I've build a website that will be going live soon and just have a couple questions about preventing SQL injection, I understand how to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` but I'm just wondering if I have to use that on all variables that I'm getting for my SQL statement and do I have to use it when I'm doing select statements also or just on insert update and delete? Also what other security would you recommend me implementing before I put the site live, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: My question was related to `mysqli_real_escape_string` the question your talking about is about  SQL injection in general...

Comment: This question should not have been closed. It was specific to mysqli and is not answered in the link provided by the censors.

Comment: @JG Estiot - well said, too many anal coders - guy needs help - so help him, sometimes takes less effort to answer than explain why you do not want to answer! I agree with you

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Any query can be injected whether it's read or write, persistent or transient.  Injections can be performed by ending one query and running a separate one (possible with `mysqli`), which renders the intended query irrelevant.

Any input to a query from an external source whether it is from users or even internal should be considered an argument to the query, and a parameter in the context of the query.  Any parameter in a query needs to be parameterized.  This leads to a properly parameterized query that you can create a prepared statement from and execute with arguments.  For example:

```
SELECT col1 FROM t1 WHERE col2 = ?
```

`?` is a placeholder for a parameter.  Using `mysqli`, you can create a prepared statement using `prepare`, bind a variable (argument) to a parameter using `bind_param`, and run the query with `execute`.  You don't have to sanitize the argument at all (in fact it's detrimental to do so).  `mysqli` does that for you.  The full process would be:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1 FROM t1 WHERE col2 = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $col2_arg);
$stmt->execute();
```

There is also an important distinction between *parameterized query* and *prepared statement*.  This statement, while prepared, is not parameterized and is thus vulnerable to injection:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ($_POST[user_input])");
```

To summarize:

- ***All*** Queries should be properly parameterized (unless they have no parameters)
- ***All*** arguments to a query should be treated as hostile as possible no matter their source

Comment: it would be nice to show how to use these magic statements with IN or SET clause with arbitrary number of elements. Otherwise it would be more like a TV ad - easy on screen but unusable at home.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think that's a bit out of the scope of this question, but I tend to do something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10698906/454533

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! This seems like a better solution than using `mysqli_real_escape_string` I'll defiantly look a little more into this and then implement it, Thank you so much!

Comment: there are no mysqli prepared statements used in the topic you linked

Comment: @YourCommonSense is this better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php

Comment: Not quite. PHP changed the rules since then, and this code would rather throw an error instead of query result