# session variables are not inserting in database in php and mysql form

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, session-variables

It is not inserting the session variables like `name, id ,email, number` like which is stored in `$a,$b,$c,$d` in `pseller.php`

This is my login page where i am checking username and password

> login.php

```
  <?php


     error_reporting(E_ALL); // to see if there is error in code


     include "connect_to_mysql.php";
     if(isset($_POST['log']))
     {

      $user= $_POST['user'];
      $pass= md5($_POST['pass']);

      $sql=mysql_query( "select * from reg where username= '$user' AND password='$pass' AND category='product seller' LIMIT 1 ") or die( mysql_error());
      $data=mysql_num_rows($sql);
      if ($data == 1) {
         $_SESSION['name']=$name;
            $_SESSION['id']=$id;
            $_SESSION['phone_no']=$number;
            $_SESSION['email_id']=$email;

        header("location:pseller.php");

       }


    else {
    header("location:login.php?error");

         }
    }
    ?>



         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                 <title> Log In </title>
                     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                      </head>

                   <body>



        <div id="mainWrapper">

     <div id="pageContent"><br /><br /><br />
      <div align="right" style="margin-right:24px; color:#FF0000">

  <br /><br />
  <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="login.php">
    <h2 style="padding-right:200px;">User Name:</h2>
      <input name="user" type="text" id="user" size="40" style="height:30px;" required placeholder="Enter Email"/>
   <br /><br />
    <h2 style="padding-right:210px;">Password:</h2>
   <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" size="40" style="height:30px;" required/>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />

   <img style="padding-right:190px;" src="generate.php"><br /><br />
   <input type="text" name="secure" size="10" required placeholder="Enter The Value" style="padding-right:210px; height:30px;">
       <br />
   <br />
   <br />
     <input type="submit" name="log" id="log" value="Log In"  style="padding-right:40px;" />





  </form>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
   </div>
    <br />
     <br />
    <br />
   </div>

       </div>
        </body>
         </html>
```

This is `pseller` page where I am trying to store session values in variables then inserting in database. but session variables are not inserting data in database and showing the value of `v_id v_number as 0`.

> pseller.php

```
    <?php 
    // Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system

    include_once('connect_to_mysql.php');
    session_start();

   if (isset($_POST['p_name'])) {


       $target_dir = "pics/";
       $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
       $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) ;
       $img_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];


        $a=$_SESSION['name'];
        $b=$_SESSION['id'];
        $c=$_SESSION['phone_no'];
        $d=$_SESSION['email_id'];

     $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['p_name']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
   $subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subcategory']);
   $category2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category2']);
    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system

  // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO product (p_name, price, details, category, sub_category, category2, img_name, v_id, v_name, v_number, v_email, date) VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category','$subcategory','$category2','$img_name','$b','$a','$c','$d',now())") or die (mysql_error());



   }
   ?>
```

Please help me to come out from here.

Comment: your second chunk shows nothing to suggest that v_id and v_number would be anything other than 0. $b $c. Do an echo

Comment: like how.. i didnt get you.

Comment: in your login.php try adding session_start(); at the top,
once started you can then set the variables (which you have done further down on the page) and they will transfer over when you call pseller.php and start the session there

Comment: $b is the first one, $c is the second one

Comment: i had opened the session_start() in earlier part of my page..  so this is not error bro. @benjayhutton

Comment: $b,$c @CliffBurton ... here they are check man man

Comment: Can you include all the code for Pseller and login.php?
the error maybe in what you have missed out on here ^_^

Comment: this is really long code... the other missing code is mostly html insertion form .. there is no php code there man. @hen jay hutton

Comment: dosent matter :) the more we have the easier it is to help debug it.
Otherwise we will be suggesting things you have already done and get nowhere.
please include the code

Comment: ok wait let me include this

Comment: upvote for question at least the OP sticks around and helps supply info. Refreshing :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so judging from the question and discussion in the comments, you're lacking proper handling of the user data in `login.php`.

There are also a couple of other points that are a bit off in your code:

1. You should not the mysql library as it's deprecated. You should either use mysqli, which is a rather easy switch if you're already used to mysql, or use PDO
2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements when using user input in SQL queries. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282103/php-mysqli-prevent-sql-injection) for example
3. MD5 is not a very secure option for passwords. You can read more [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)

Below is a simple example of the PHP part for `login.php` I threw together based on what information I could gather from your question. It isn't complete for your specific database structure and needs, but should help you forward with your problem:

```
<?php

  // Define database connection using mysqli
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");

  if(isset($_POST['log']))
  {
    $user= $_POST['user'];
    $pass= md5($_POST['pass']); // Should be replaced by secure alternatives

    // Define the SQL query string
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, phone_no, email FROM reg WHERE email = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); // Prepare the query string
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass); // Define prepared statement parameters

    // Execute the prepared stament
    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        $result = $stmt->get_result(); // Get the result

        $data = $result->num_rows; // Get number of rows

        if ($data == 1)
        {
          $userdata = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Get an associative array from the result

          $_SESSION['name'] = $userdata['name'];
          $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
          $_SESSION['phone_no'] = $userdata['phone_no'];
          $_SESSION['email_id'] = $userdata['email'];

          header("location:pseller.php");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        header("location:login.php?error");
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
$_SESSION['phone_no']=$number;
```

**only get updated if select with username and password has rowcount 1**

Those become variables `$b` and `$c` in pseller.php

So if $user and $pass do not get you a row on select from db, you get junk in `SESSION`.

`mysql_num_rows returns` number of rows. You are doing LIMIT 3. So if you are 0, 2, or 3, **session is in trouble**. Why, because your if statement says =1.

Also, you are using a deprecated mysql_* function library and acting directly upon user-supplied values that can render sql injection attacks. Use mysqli or pdo, and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496).

Comment: can you explain me what i have to do here.. to to get those variable.

Comment: so what changes i have to do in my login.php code.. tell me that stuff bro...then may be i will get you.. how i am not giving those parameter

Comment: I would start with echoing out some variable values. Perhaps an echo also inside the if statement that sets those two SESSION variables, so that you know you even got the user/pass combo successfully

Comment: play with it. I don't see what you have done. I was suggesting why they are equal to 0

Answer (score 2):

Include `session_start(); in your`login.php

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from reg where username= '$user' 
AND password='$pass' AND category='product seller'") or die( mysql_error());
```

Inside the above query, Please make the changes.

Avoid making column names with spaces `category='product seller'`
Now echo the values under the `SELECT * FROM` query and the `$a, $b, $c, $d` to know if you REALLY are taking the values through to the next page. I am pretty much sure that you were not and also  @Drew suggested, shift to `msqli/PDO`.

**EDIT:**

In your second page `pseller.php` try to echo and see what you're getting.

```
 echo   $_SESSION['name'];
 echo   $_SESSION['id'];
 echo   $_SESSION['phone_no'];
 echo   $_SESSION['email_id'];
```

No luck? Okay let's just try it this way and see what happens;

```
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from reg where username= '$user' AND password='$pass'") or die( mysql_error());

      if ($sql) {
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
           echo     $row['name'];
           echo     $row['id'];
           echo     $row['phone_no'];
           echo     $row['email_id'];
 }   
    //        header("location:pseller.php");
           }
```

Now put the correct username and password (present in the database) and if you can see the echoed values, use sessions to store and use them later on also uncomment the `header();` line and you are good to go.

Comment: man.. its not changing the view.. facing same problem.. i tried this.

Comment: where i should echo $a, $b and all?? in pseller.php page

Comment: i tried this edited version too.. but still not working.. and it is not showing any values of echo session statements.

Comment: v_id,v_number are 0 while other two v_email, v_user are blank in the databse it is showing this.

Comment: @komaldeepsinghchahal please try with this updated edit and remember it won't work if the query fails.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\venders\login.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\venders\login.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined variable: number in C:\xampp\htdocs\venders\login.php on line 47

Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\venders\login.php on line 48

Comment: Where exactly are you defining the variables you're trying to store in the sessions variables in login.php ($name, $id, $number, $email)?

Comment: even if i remove error.. it is again not showing values on thsi page too

Comment: no i am trying to store the session variables of login .php in seller.php page...thats why i used session

Comment: do you like coming on my pc through teamviewer..??

Comment: @komaldeepsinghchahal if you can get the echo values now then you can easily store them using using sessions

Comment: but these are not echoing the values bro.

Comment: give me ur email id ... so i will send you id and password.

Comment: I meant, where are you pulling those values, that you are trying to save to the session, from? Your code example doesn't show you defining the $name, $id, $number and $email variables and that bit of the error log you posted also insinuated that they are not defined.

Comment: @harris i am trying these values to pseller.php after getting from login .php. so what should i do man.

Comment: @komal deep singh chahal But WHERE are you getting those values from? I take it you get them from the MySQL query? Your code doesn't show you handling the MySQL resultset and defining the said values.

Comment: exactly.. i think i am missing this part.... like tell me how to these values writting mysql querry... tell me how to hndle myswl resultset and defining thses values.

Comment: Well, first off you shouldn't use PHP's mysql library as it's deprecated, but instead use mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). For mysqli you should look into fetch_assoc for hints on handling the data (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). Also for your queries you should look into prepared statements for security reasons (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).