# Undefined index: quantity

Tags: session, undefined

I am having a small problem updating my cart because of "undefined index:quantity message coming up on my text box.On the last line of my code. what is wrong with the code? Any kind consideration will be highly appreciated.

```
    function edit_quantity(){
      if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){
        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
          $sql3="UPDATE Shopcart set qty='$quantity'";
          $sql3_run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
         $_SESSION['quantity']=$quantity;
         $total=$total*$quantity;
        }
       echo $_SESSION['quantity'];

      }
```

Comment: You have to call `session_start();` first before using `$_SESSION`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282103/php-mysqli-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see you dont have `session_start();`

put  it somewhere before you use `$_SESSION`

edit:

your code might not enter the if block and would not set the `quantity` session. That's why you are having an `Undefied index error` move the echo statement inside the if block so that it will echo when your `quantity` session is set.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply, I have a session _start on the top of the php page.

Comment: moving the echo statement  to when the session statement was set cleared the error. Thank you for your swift response much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the POST data does not have a `quantity` value. You are only checking for an `update_cart` post value before proceeding to update the session.

As others have mentioned, there is also a serious sql injection problem with your code which you should fix.