# prevent sql injection in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am very new to mysqli earlier i am writing queries in mysql but mysqli is more advanced so, i am first time using it.
Below is my php code.

```
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

        $email = clean($_POST['email']);
        $password = clean($_POST['password']);
        //$password =md5($password);


    if(empty($res['errors'])) {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT uid FROM users where email='$email' and password = '$password'");
        if($result->num_rows == 1){
            $res['success'] = true;
        }
        else{
            array_push($res['errors'], 'Invalid login details');
            $res['success'] = false;

        }
    }else{
        $res['success'] = false;        
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

clean function is not working as expected because sql queries return false if i enter username and password correct.
So, it seems like this is not valid in mysqli case.

I checked this link [PHP MySQLI Prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282103/php-mysqli-prevent-sql-injection) and got to know that we have to prepare query.

I can see there is an example but i am not able to understand how to prepare/bind if i have to use two or more form data.

Thanks for your time.

**Updated code**

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT uid FROM users where email=:email and password = :password");
        $result->execute([
':email' => $email,
         ':password' => $password]);
        //$result->execute();
        if($result->num_rows == 1){
        //if(mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {
            $res['success'] = true;

        }
        else{
            array_push($res['errors'], 'Invalid login details');
            $res['success'] = false;

        }
```

Comment: use redbeanphp which is built on pdo.

Comment: reason is, you're mixing MySQL APIs, you can't do that if you're still using `return mysql_real_escape_string($str);` with your present/new code. Just get rid of all that and use a prepared statement. Plus, we don't know if there are any values in your POST arrays since you didn't post your HTML form.

Comment: we also don't know which API you're (now) using to connect with. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other? Then you have `if($result->num_rows == 1){` that is `mysqli_` syntax and your `where email=:email and password = :password` is PDO. Again, they do NOT intermix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated in comments, you need to be consistent with your API choice. [You can't mix APIs in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php).

You started out with `mysqli_*`, so I'll continue with that. You had some `mysql_*` and PDO in there, and it might not be a bad idea to use PDO over `mysqli_*` - but if your server supports `mysqli_*`, there is nothing wrong with using that. See [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and decide for yourself (just stay away from `mysql_*`, it's outdated).

Using `mysqli_*`, you connect to the database like this (you didn't show your connection).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

As for preventing SQL injection in it self, all you need is to use prepared statements. You can still *clean* or sanitize your data if there are some kind of values you don't want sitting in your tables - but that's kind of another discussion.

You also need to know if your passwords are hashed in the database. **They really should be**, and you should be using [`password_hash($password, $algorithm)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and  [`password_verify($password, $hash)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) if you're on PHP5.5 and above (if not, look into something like [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)).

You need to be consistent with your hashes too, you can't insert it with `md5` and selecting it with no hash. It all needs to be the same. Because if you are selecting an `md5` hash, and comparing it to an unhashed string, they will be different, and the query fails.

I'm showing you an example of using `password_verify()`, so that means that the password stored in the database will also need to be stored with `password_hash()` (or your query fails).

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT uid, password FROM users where email=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);           // Bind variable to the placeholder
    $stmt->execute();                                 // Execute query
    $stmt->bind_result($userID, $password);         // Set the selected columns into the variables
    $stmt->fetch();                                   // ...and fetch it
    if ($stmt->num_rows) {
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Password was correct and matched the email!
        } else {
            // Password was incorrect...
        }
    } else {
        // Accountname not found
    } 
}
```

This is just a basic example, but it will get you started. **Never trust user input**, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind more variables like so:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT uid FROM users where email= ? and password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

As you can see, you can expand on the `bind_param()` function. You can also add different type of variables:

```
i   corresponding variable has type integer
d   corresponding variable has type double
s   corresponding variable has type string
b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try. Voted Up.

Comment: Still it is giving me same error. Invalid username password.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest you learn PDO instead of MySQLi, just because it supports more drivers.

Second, you use mysql_real_escape_string, as you might see, that is a MySQL function, not a MySQLi function.

So where you have:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT uid FROM users where email='$email' and password = '$password'");
```

You should do something like:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT uid FROM users where email = :email AND password = :password");
try{
$stmt->execute([
    ':email' => $email,
    ':password' => $password
]);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Remove when putting online
}

if($stmt->num_rows){
    $res['success'] = true;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First i will learn mysqli then i will move to PDO. Voted up.

Comment: @404 If this helped you, please click the button under the V button to mark it as an answer. It will help other people in the future as well. I also want to note that you don't have to use the clean() function with this anymore as far as I know.

Comment: Can you please advise me how to use email and password both in query. you gave me example of email only.

Comment: Just add the same as for email, only change the words to password, in the query and in the execution.

Comment: I tried but not working. i am updating the code in question.

Comment: Try my updated code and tell me if you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

You're presently mixing MySQL APIs/functions with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, then `num_rows` and then a PDO binding method `where email=:email and password = :password` which seems to have been taken from another answer given for your question.

- **Those different functions do NOT intermix.**

You must use the same one from connection to querying.

- Consult: [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

It looks like you're wanting to setup a login script. I suggest you use the following and pulled from one of ircmaxell's answers:

Pulled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above)
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

It's safer and uses a safe password hashing method, rather than what you seem to want to use is MD5 `$password =md5($password);` and is no longer considered safe to use now.

References:

- PDO connection http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
- PDO error handling http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- To check if a user exists, you can see one of my answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Sidenote: If you do go that route, remember to read the manuals and that your password column is long enough to hold the hash. Minimum length is 60, but they recommend 255.

It is also unclear if your HTML form does have name attributes for the POST arrays, so make sure the form is using a POST method.

- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

I believe I have given you enough information to get started.

---

What you must NOT do, is to use the above with your present code and simply patching it. You need to start over.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: what is the draw back if we create own hasing function?

Comment: @404 it's just more work really. Why not just use the functions that are already written, tried-tested-and-true? ;-) and you may end up creating code that could be broken by a hacker.