# Doubts of security: Mysqli vs PDO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, sql-injection

i've started to create my website, but now i have few doubts. I've searched, that MySqli object oriented is good to use because you can prepare the queries, use bind_param and execute. The MySqli from my website looks like this: [PHP MySQLI Prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282103/php-mysqli-prevent-sql-injection)

But, this is good enough? My website need a good code like this to become more secure for SQL Injection, but it makes me immune for DDoS and defaces?

Backing to the topic: Mysqli is equal to PDO in secure and performance?

Comment: But he is not asking about security or performance, is searching for a preference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in security, but only in usability. 
Mysqli is unusable as is, leaving PDO the only choice.

Comment: Why? it's too complicated? outdated ?

Comment: Well, it's not finished yet, but here you go: https://phpdelusions.net/usab

Comment: I started to use PDO, converting my code using this tutorial https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions. I am eager to get any feedback to improve the article.

Comment: Okay! Thanks, this article give a good help, i already converted a login and a register script from mysqli to PDO. I learned instantly. My only doubt so far is: PDO doens't have to close connect and stmt? like $mysqli->close();

Comment: Well, for a connection you don't need it most of time for mysqli either - PHP will close it automatically on the script's end. As of the statement, although you may, but if you are calling it within a function, it will be automatically closed at the function's end, as well if you are rewriting it. But if you want to close it, just write `$stmt = null;`