# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\PTT\login.php on line 28

Here's line 28:

```
$voornaam    = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['voornaam']);
```

Here's my code:

```
//Generate a key, print a form:
$key = sha1(microtime());
$_SESSION['csrf'] = $key;


if(isset($_POST['registreer'])){
$voornaam    = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['voornaam']);
$achternaam  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['achternaam']);
$land    = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['land']);
$gebdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day']);
$inlognaam   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inlognaam']);
$wachtwoord  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['wachtwoord']);
$wachtwoord_nogmaals = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['wachtwoord_nogmaals']);
$wachtwoordmd5   = md5($wachtwoord);
$email   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$wereld  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['wereld']);
$secondaccount = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['agreecheck']);
$schelden = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['agreecheck2']);

$ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$character = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['character']);
$referer     = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['referer']);
$check = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("SELECT `ip_aangemeld`, `aanmeld_datum` FROM `gebruikers` WHERE `ip_aangemeld`='".$ip."' ORDER BY `user_id` DESC"));
$registerdate = strtotime($check['aanmeld_datum']);
$current_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$countdown_time = 604800-($current_time-$registerdate);
```

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php link, you should add "mysql $link" to this function

Comment: What's the problem? When an error message says a function requires 2 arguments and that 1 was given, it means there is one required argument that is missing. `2-1=1`.

Comment: Sorry, this is a very low quality question as it shows no effort in researching and fixing the error. Checking google or the php manual would have told you to add the variable, which holds the mysqli link ressource, to `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Please start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282103/php-mysqli-prevent-sql-injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: That helped but a new issue approached

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: land in C:\wamp\www\PTT\login.php on line 30

$land  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['land']);

Comment: Then see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: I honestly have to say I see no reason why this post has been downvoted 7 times. I left you an upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like the warning says: you are missing an argument in mysqli_real_escape_string, you should add your db connection as an argument:

```
    $voornaam    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['voornaam']);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Escaping with `mysql_real_escape_string` is **inadequate** in preventing SQL injection Attacks, use prepared statements instead.

You need to add the mysqli connection link identifier as the first parameter:

```
$voornaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['voornaam']);
```

*Note: replace `$con` with your database variable.*

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass your connection variable as one of the two variables of the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function
Eg.

```
$a = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['a']);
```