# PHP not Reading <select> name for MySQL Update

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a fantasy football database just for fun and I have made some progress with a PHP page but am stuck with an issue in getting data from my html data to be read by my php update script (update.php)

Here's my code for the form:

```
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "nottelling";
  $dbname = "Football";

  // Create connection

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // Check connection

  if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sqlqb = "SELECT Name_Team_Position FROM Football.2016_Players_QB;";
  $resultqb = $conn->query($sqlqb);
  echo " <form method=\"post\" action=\"update.php\"> <br> Enter Passcode:";
  echo " <input name = \"Passcode\" type = \"text\"> </input> <br><br> ";
  echo " Pick your QB: <select name='QB'> </option> "; // list box select command
  foreach ($conn->query($sqlqb) as $row){         
    // Array or records stored in $row
    echo " <option value=$row[id]>$row[Name_Team_Position]</option> "; 
    /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
  }  
  echo " </select> ";// Closing of list box
  echo " <br><br> <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"> </input> ";
  echo " </form> ";
  $conn->close();
 ?>
```

And here's update.php

```
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "nottelling";
  $dbname = "Football";

  // Create connection

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // Check connection

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $value1 = $_POST['Passcode'];
  $value2 = $_POST['QB'];

  $sql = "UPDATE Football.PlayerTeams SET QB = '$value2' WHERE Password = '$value1';";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }

  $conn->close();

?>
```

My problem as concisely as I can put it:

This script is definitely connecting properly to the DB and executing the update query successfully. The problem is that $value1 is not receiving any value from the html form. If I insert the string "test" into the row corresponding with the passcode, and then I use the form this code producing, it runs successfully but then when I check the db "test" is gone and instead its just blank - "". Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong in trying to get the drop-down value to my action script?

Comment: Your code is flawed, `$row[id]` cannot exist, because `id` in PHP is read as a constant instead of a string `'id'`. This is some very basic PHP right here. You would have figured this out if you enabled error reporting. You didn't. Enable it while developing, it is... ***that*** easy. Secondly, perhaps you should read on [`mysql_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) (and take a note of the huge red block) because apparently, you don't care about mysql injections so why are you using `mysqli`?

Comment: @Xorifelse Congratulations, you've succeeded in verbally attacking a person who doesn't know much PHP!

Comment: I didn't learn because my teacher was nice to me, you should act on the given information and [enable error reporting first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34789044/4982088), squash out the warnings 1 by 1, update your code to [prevent mysql injections](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16282269/4982088). After that, check if `var_dump($_POST)` contains the correct values.

Comment: Secondly, you might want to create a file called `db.php` and paste [this](http://pastebin.com/Xi6frW5C) code into it. Now, for your `update.php` and `index.php` you can just do `include 'db.php'` and do `$conn = getdbconn();` saves a lot of time when you need to change your server settings.

Comment: @Xorifelse you seem to miss the fact that there were no errors here. Just incorrect value names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
echo " Pick your QB: <select name='QB'> </option> ";
```

The `</option>` are wrong placed

Replace:  `echo " Pick your QB: <select name='QB'>";`

Replace:   `echo " <br><br> <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">";`

The $row['id'] is the value that you become in your QB if your POST.

```
echo " <option value='TheValueYouNeededHere'>Display Name</option> ";
```

And for POST use `filter_input` — Gets a specific external variable by name and optionally filters it:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, QB, filter);
```

The filters you find here: http://php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.php

Copy from User:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Football.PlayerTeams SET QB = '".$value2."' WHERE Password = '".$value1."'";
```

Is more beautiful for the eyes, you must not use ".$Value." In php works without i mean, correct me when i'm wrong

Security:

Your MySQL query can easy injected. And your passwort is Visible.
It gives multiple choices to avoid this.

MySQL injecton: 
You can replace some char's. (Char are single character) 
The most dangerous things you can replace with other characters. Filter Input have nice filters like htmlspecialchars. I Think you find much things if you search little :)

Password:
First make `<input type='password'>`.
Then Hash your password or pick MD5 or something to make it "unreadeble". You can set it on MySQL. With PHP u build the "secure" value.
MD5 is not the best option. Its only easy to implement for beginning.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `$row[id]`... dont you mean `$row['id']`??

Comment: I seem to copy paste myself all over the other answers, you are suggesting a mysql injection... mysqli is perfectly cableable of preventing that.

Comment: it gives much ways to prevent mysql injection ;)

Comment: @ivorysmoker you came the closest - I've now solved the problem with your help. First you noticed the erroneous </option> which was solid but you also noted value='$row[id]', which should have just been "$row[Name_Team_Position]", as soon as I corrected it to this I succeeded in getting the submitted string into the database.

Thank you also for your correct additional advice on SQL injection attacks. This database contains no PI information of any kind and the connection details listed above are not the ones I will actually use. This question was meant in a "sandbox", non-internet context.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following and let me know.

```
echo " Pick your QB: <select name='QB'> </option> "; // list box select command
foreach ($conn->query($sqlqb) as $row){
echo " <option value=$row[id]>$row[Name_Team_Position]</option> ";
```

into
    echo " Pick your QB: "; // list box select command
    while($row = $resultqb->fetch_assoc()){
    echo " ".$row['Name_Team_Position']." ";

```
$sql = "UPDATE Football.PlayerTeams SET QB = '$value2' WHERE Password = '$value1';";
```

Into

```
$sql = "UPDATE Football.PlayerTeams SET QB = '".$value2."' WHERE Password = '".$value1."'";
```

Comment: This will not work, `id` would be considered a constant instead of an array index. Secondly, inlining arrays should be done with `{` and `}`

Comment: Now you are suggesting a mysql injection... mysqli is perfectly cableable of preventing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
foreach ($conn->query($sqlqb) as $row)

{  // Array or records stored in $row

echo " <option value=$row[id]>$row[Name_Team_Position]</option> "; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */
```

with

```
while($row = $resultqb->fetch_assoc()) 

{  // Array or records stored in $row

echo " <option value=$row['id']>$row['Name_Team_Position']</option> "; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */
```

**Edit**
Array index should be in strings.

Comment: This will not work, 'id' and 'Name_Team_Position' would be considered a constant instead of an array index. Secondly, inlining arrays should be done with `{` and `}`

Comment: Just part of code is to be replaced and yes every index should be string, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you have nothing in you value attribute of option. Try to inspect options tag you will see your `value =$row[id]` which is senseless try to use this

```
echo " <option value='".$row['id']."'>$row['Name_Team_Position']</option> ";
```

or

```
foreach ($conn->query($sqlqb) as $row)

  { ?>

 <option value=<?php echo $row[id];?>><?php echo $row['Name_Team_Position'];?></option>


 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: That go's for you too, 'id' would be considered a constant instead of an array index.