# phpmyadmin server conncetion localhost/login.php not posting anything

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

What is physically wrong with this code.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = "1234";
$user_pass = "4321";
$mysql_qry = "SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE username like '$user_name' 
&& password like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result > 0) {
echo "login success";
}
else{
echo "login not success";
}

?>
```

(when I run it on the local host, there is nothing there [localhost/login.php])

Comment: check for errors! (mysqli_error)

Comment: all of the username and password are in the mysql database

Comment: What errors are you talking about?

Comment: the errors you'll get back from mysqli if the query fails. Also enable [php error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: You see nothing because the comilation fails. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. I am a beginner.

Comment: Apart from the missing bracket after if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) reported by Atal Prateek, your code is trivially exploitable by an attacker in two ways: Bypass the check by using a password of % which is a meta-character for LIKE. The second way is to exploit the username by SQL Injection - you should be using prepared statements to avoid that, google the term or find info on it on stackoverflow e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282103/php-mysqli-prevent-sql-injection. Also, remove the ending semicolon from the query you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should remove `;` from the query string

before

```
"SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE username like '$user_name' 
&& password like '$user_pass';";
```

after
and also you can use `&&` or `and` keyword

```
 "SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE username like '".$user_name."' 
and password like '".$user_pass."'";
```

and write syntax near if condition
missing rounded bracket

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "login success";
}
else{
echo "login not success";
}
```

Comment: 1) The `;` is not an error, just a convension! 2) It is not necessary to start and stop a double quoted string to expand scalar variables

Comment: 3) You can use `AND` and also `&&` if you want so also not an error

Comment: ya you rigth  && , and both allowed

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing bracket in if statement after '$result'.
it should be

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = "1234";
$user_pass = "4321";
$mysql_qry = "SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE username like '$user_name' 
               && password like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   echo "login success";
}
else{
   echo "login not success";
}
?>
```

you had one problem. Refer http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```