# PHP - Delete many items from database with one array of IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have this array

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "4" [3]=> string(1) "5" }
```

Where every element of this array is ID of post.
In mysql, table posts, column ID.

DELETE query for one ID would be something like

`DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $id`

I can make look through this array and make delete query on each of them.

But they are 4. So it will be 4 queries. And If I had 70? 70 queries....

And question is, how to delete all posts at once having this array of IDs?

Comment: Use `WHERE id IN ()`

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698524/parameterised-in-clause-in-prepared-statement-using-mysql-php-and-adodb).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First use `implode()` to create a string from your array, then use `WHERE id IN ()`:

```
$ids = implode("','", $array);
queryMethod("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id IN ('".$ids."')");
```

[PHP Manual: Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)